# reactjs Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

I have used `getInitialState` on my `BrowseWidgetBox` component. Although when passing the data to my `MainMenu` component, the data remains empty, as if the AJAX call to the api was never run in the `BrowseWidgetBox`.

My question then, is why is this happening? Shouldn't `componentDidMount` call the ajax api and re-set the state to include the contents of the ajax call? I want the state of my groupsData and my itemData to be present when the page is initially loaded. I am a bit worried that `getInitialState` is hindering the calls to ajax at least 'initially' which is causing my error.

Here is the full code of the two components:

```
var MainMenu = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                    console.log(this.props.groupsData);   // console.log here 
                    var categories = this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj){
                        return (<li>obj.description</li>);   
                    });
                    return (<div className="MainMenu">
                            <ul>{categories}</ul>

                        </div>);
                }
            });

var BrowseWidgetBox = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function () {
                      return {groupsData: {}, itemsData: {}};
                },
                getGroupsApi: function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.props.groupsApi,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(groupsData){
                            this.setState({groupsData: groupsData});
                            console.log(groupsData)     // Console.log here 
                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function(xhr, status, err){
                            console.error(this.props.groupsApi ,status, err.toString());
                        }.bind(this)
                    });

                },
                getItemsApi: function() {
                 $.ajax({
                        url: this.props.itemsApi,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(itemsData){
                            this.setState({itemsData: itemsData});
                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function(xhr, status, err){
                            console.error(this.props.groupsApi ,status, err.toString());
                        }.bind(this)
                    });
                },
                componentDidMount: function() {
                    this.getGroupsApi();
                    this.getItemsApi();
                },
                render: function() {
                    return (<div className="BrowseWidgetBox">
                                <MainMenu groupsData={this.state.groupsData} itemsData={this.state.itemsData} />
                                <Display  />
                            </div>);
                }
            });



                React.render(
                    <BrowseWidgetBox groupsApi="http://this/is/a/good/url" itemsApi="http://this/is/a/good/api/call" />, document.getElementById('widget-container')
                );
```

Comment: Have you tried defining your data as empty arrays instead of empty objects in "getInitialState" ? Once you fetch your data you process it with map() which is a method of array not object...

Comment: Yes, I have. I still received the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the map in object...

In

```
 getInitialState: function () {
         return {groupsData: {}, itemsData: { objects: [] }};
 },
```

the first render are getting a object in groupsData
try change to

```
var MainMenu = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                    console.log(this.props.groupsData);   // console.log here 
                    var categories = this.props.groupsData.objects.map(function(obj){
                        return (<li>obj.description</li>);   
                    });
                    return (<div className="MainMenu">
                            <ul>{categories}</ul>

                        </div>);
                }
            });

var BrowseWidgetBox = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function () {
                      return {groupsData:  { objects: [] }, itemsData: []};
                },
                getGroupsApi: function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.props.groupsApi,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(groupsData){
                            this.setState({groupsData: groupsData});
                            console.log(groupsData)     // Console.log here 
                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function(xhr, status, err){
                            console.error(this.props.groupsApi ,status, err.toString());
                        }.bind(this)
                    });

                },
                getItemsApi: function() {
                 $.ajax({
                        url: this.props.itemsApi,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(itemsData){
                            this.setState({itemsData: itemsData});
                        }.bind(this),
                        error: function(xhr, status, err){
                            console.error(this.props.groupsApi ,status, err.toString());
                        }.bind(this)
                    });
                },
                componentDidMount: function() {
                    this.getGroupsApi();
                    this.getItemsApi();
                },
                render: function() {
                    return (<div className="BrowseWidgetBox">
                                <MainMenu groupsData={this.state.groupsData} itemsData={this.state.itemsData} />
                                <Display  />
                            </div>);
                }
            });



                React.render(
                    <BrowseWidgetBox groupsApi="http://this/is/a/good/url" itemsApi="http://this/is/a/good/api/call" />, document.getElementById('widget-container')
                );
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it. But that seems to make no difference. As I still get the same error. Not to mention, the JSON contains an array.